Is ∀x(Ax→Bx), where “→” is connexive implication, equivalent to ∀x(¬Ax∨Bx)?
Is ∀x(Ax→Bx), where “→” is connexive implication, equivalent to ∀x(¬Ax∨Bx)? I ask because of the following. According to one of my interlocutors, the negation of the connexive implication ∀x(Ax→Bx) is ∃x(Ax∧¬Bx). Yet this seems wrong though because there seems to be a real distinction between the connexive conditional and the material conditional. And as such, the connexive implication ∀x(Ax→Bx) is not identical to ∀x(¬Ax∨Bx). Thus, the negation of the connexive implication should be another connexive implication. However, I could be wrong though.

Can you be more specific about which axiom system of connexive logic you are working in?

"∀x(Ax→Bx), where “→” is connexive implication" Could you give a concrete example of a "connexive" implication?

My example in your other recent question may have been misleadingly worded. I have corrected it. You are correct to say that in connexive logics, Ax → Bx is not logically equivalent to ¬Ax ∨ Bx.

Weak connexive logic is mainly used for more stringent reasoning such as applied in philosophical reasoning like Aritotle's thesis ¬(p→¬p), so the negation of ∀x(Ax→Bx) is ∃x(Ax∧¬Bx), where you can easily verify that when A=B leads to contradiction which is exactly Aritotle's thesis which asserts that no proposition can imply its own negation. Only if you're concerned with a stronger connexive logic accepting Boethius' Thesis, the negation will become ∀x(Ax→¬Bx)...

@causative, the logical system I am working in is the following: 1.¬(A→B)↔(A→¬B)
2. (A→B)↔(¬B→¬A)
3. ¬∀x(Ax→Bx)↔∃x(¬(Ax→Bx))
4. And by personal extrapolation: ∃x(¬(Ax→Bx))↔∃x(Ax→¬Bx)

Well, I don't think so, but maybe it depends on what system you're working in. Based on the three-valued truth tables given on SEP for Cantwell's system CN, we can compare a->b to a~b and ~avb:
a   b   a->b    ~b  a~b ~avb
-   -   -       -   -   -
-   t   t       f   f   t
-   f   f       t   -   -
t   -   -       -   -   -
t   t   t       f   f   t
t   f   f       t   t   f
f   -   -       -   f   t
f   t   -       f   f   t
f   f   -       t   f   t

Based on this, a->b is not the same as ~avb. The negation of a->b is not the same as a~b. Also, given that the negation of a->b is true, this does not imply that a~b is true; if a is - and b is f, then ~(a->b) is true but a~b is -.
But there are other systems of connexive logic and maybe your interlocutors are right in some of them.
